# Fork() from inside a spawned Thread in Python issue

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, thread-safety, fork

I'am having problemes to kill the child processes from a fork spawn inside an also spawned thread:

```
_td = threading.Thread(target=updateProxies,args=())
_td.start()

def updateProxies():
    quota = 25
    children = []
    sons = 0
    for i in range(50):
        pid = os.fork()
        if pid:
            children.append(pid)
            sons+=1
            if sons >= quota:
                os.wait()
                sons-=1
        else:
             {CHILD CODE EXECUTION} #database calls, and network requests
             sys.exit()
    for x in children:
        os.waitpid(x,0)
```

When I run the code above, the parent from the children stops at the "os.waitpid(x,0)" line, and never resumes from there. And yes, I tracked all the children until they die at their respectively sys.exit(), but waitpid never gets informed about their death and my parent process never resumes! 
When doing ps -ef, the childs processes are (defunct) aren't they diyng?

IMPORTANT: when I execute the function from the main thread, everything goes fine. How to deal with it?

Answer (score 3):

FOUND THE ANSWER:
Had to exit the fork processes with:

```
os._exit(0)
```

not with

```
sys.exit()
```